# Can't push to Firebase using html form

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

To everyone that knows about Firebase, HTML and Javascript.

Trying to post to Firebase database using input form in HTML but just couldn't make it work.

Already set the database and everything but it isn't showing up. No errors are being returned.

Can you help me?

This is the HTML

```
<form id="recommendationForm">
    <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon" id="sel0">Name</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex.: 1832" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="os-input">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sel1">Type:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
            <option selected value="1">Fixed</option>
            <option value="2">Mobile</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sel2">Technician:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="sel2">
                <option selected value="1">Brandon</option>
                <option value="2">Justin</option>
                <option value="3">Ryan</option>
                <option value="4">Tyler</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <br>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then here the .js file

```
/*
  initializing firebase and getting values from input
  then push the values and submit 'em
*/

$(function() {
    var config = {
        apiKey: "MY KEY",
        authDomain: "MY AUTH",
        databaseURL: "MY URL",
        projectId: "MY ID",
        storageBucket: "MY BUCKET",
        messagingSenderId: "MY ID"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var recommendations = firebase.database().ref("recommendations");
    var submitRecommendation = function() {

        // Get input values from each of the form elements
        var value1 = $("#sel0").val();
        var value2 = $("#sel1 option:selected").text();
        var value3 = $("#sel2 option:selected").text();

        // Push a new recommendation to the database using those values
        recommendations.push({
            "os": value1,
            "datepicker": value2,
            "estado": value3
        });

        $(window).load(function() {
            // Find the HTML element with the id recommendationForm, and when the submit
            // event is triggered on that element, call submitRecommendation.
            $("#recommendationForm").submit(submitRecommendation);

        });
    };
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/pimatco/dxhspx3o/

Answer (score 1):

Your form is not posting to firebase, it's doing a get request.

```
<form id="recommendationForm" method="post">
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can't `push()` directly on the ref, you have to `push()` then `set()`:

Reference in the docs
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-push

Here is a example of the edited code:

```
    recommendations.push().set({
        "os": value1,
        "datepicker": value2,
        "estado": value3
    });
```

Also you should be accessing the `child()` from your database ref to be able to push on to it.

```
var recommendations = firebase.database().ref().child("recommendations");
```

And finally you are defining your `submit` function inside the declaration of your `submitRecommendation` function

You have:

```
var submitRecommendation = function() {
  ...

    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#recommendationForm").submit(submitRecommendation);
    });
};
```

But it should be:

```
var submitRecommendation = function() {
  ...

};

$(window).load(function() {
     $("#recommendationForm").submit(submitRecommendation);
});
```

Doing all of this will allow you to push to firebase.

Comment: Thanks for that but still didn't work. it returned this error **[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.**

Comment: @MathLoures I added a bit more to the answer.

Comment: @MathLoures nothing as in nothing is entered in the database? Would you be will to make a jsfiddle to further debug the issue?

Comment: Nothing. Updated the question with it.

Comment: @MathLoures I have added to the answer